# How to keep parent displayed when child is focused?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a 3 level (or more) clickable menu, but I noticed that when I click a child, parent and his siblings hide. I would like parent and his siblings to stay displayed when children are focused. Is that possible only using CSS? Here is my code:

```
<style>
.menu{
  background: green;
}
.menu ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;    
}
.menu ul ul{background: rgba(0,0,0, .2);}
.menu >ul>li>a{  line-height: 50px; }

.menu li{
  list-style: none; 

  position: relative;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #009900;
}

.menu a:not(:only-child):after {
    padding-left: 5px;
    content: '\25BC' ' ';
}



.menu li:last-child{border: none;}
.menu li a{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Level 2*/
.menu ul > li > ul > li > a{display: block;
line-height: 0px;
overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;

}   
.menu ul>li>a:focus +ul>li>a{
    color:red;
    line-height:50px;
      -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}       

/* Level 3+ */
.menu li ul ul{ top:0;}


</style>


<html>


<div class="menu ">
    <!--Level 1-->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Level 1-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Level 1-2</a>
      <!--Level 2-->
          <ul> 
            <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Level 2-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Level 2-2</a>
            <!--Level 3-->
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Level 3-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Level 3-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Level 3-3</a></li>
                  </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Level 2-3</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Level 1-3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Level 1-4</a>
   </ul>
</div>


</html>
```

Here is a JSfiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ha3uj465/).

And the effect I want to achieve is shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yhovdc0n/). Try hover items to view it.

Comment: Did the answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I revised your code below. You had an error in your CSS selector and level 2 transition needs to be removed.

**Replace this line:**

```
.menu ul>li>a:focus+ ul>li>a{
```

**To:**

```
.menu ul>li:hover >ul>li>a{
```

And in `.menu ul > li > ul > li > a{` remove the transition.

```
-webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
```

```html
<style>
.menu{
  background: green;
}
.menu ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;    
}
.menu ul ul{background: rgba(0,0,0, .2);}
.menu >ul>li>a{  line-height: 50px; }

.menu li{
  list-style: none; 

  position: relative;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #009900;
}

.menu a:not(:only-child):after {
    padding-left: 5px;
    content: '\25BC' ' ';
}



.menu li:last-child{border: none;}
.menu li a{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Level 2*/
.menu ul > li > ul > li > a{display: block;
line-height: 0px;
overflow:hidden;
  /*-webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;*/

}   
/*.menu ul>li>a:focus+ ul>li>a{*/
.menu ul>li:hover >ul>li>a{
    color:red;
    line-height:50px;
      -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}       

/* Level 3+ */
.menu li ul ul{ top:0;}


</style>


<html>


<div class="menu ">
    <!--Level 1-->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Level 1-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Level 1-2</a>
      <!--Level 2-->
          <ul> 
            <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Level 2-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Level 2-2</a>
            <!--Level 3-->
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Level 3-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Level 3-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Level 3-3</a></li>
                  </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Level 2-3</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Level 1-3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">Level 1-4</a>
   </ul>
</div>


</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much; but remember that I need the menu for being displayed only when focused... The JSfiddle of the hovering one it was just an example of how it should look like... But thanks for pointing those corrections ;)